# How should corrupt events in a data file be removed using Python?

Tags: python, regex, corrupt

I have a data file that contains event entries of the following form:

```
<event>
 4   0  0.5048900E-01  0.1915537E+03  0.7546771E-02  0.1157067E+00
       21   -1    0    0  503  502  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.20916118194E+03  0.20916118194E+03  0.00000000000E+00 0.  1.
       21   -1    0    0  501  503  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00 -0.19069665391E+03  0.19069665391E+03  0.00000000000E+00 0.  1.
        6    1    1    2  501    0  0.64272189331E+02  0.51311781060E+02 -0.47339360468E+02  0.19731656861E+03  0.17300000000E+03 0. -1.
       -6    1    1    2    0  502 -0.64272189331E+02 -0.51311781060E+02  0.65803888495E+02  0.20254126725E+03  0.17300000000E+03 0. -1.
</event>
<event>
 4   0  0.5048900E-01  0.1923878E+03  0.7546771E-02  0.1156325E+00
       21   -1    0    0  503  502  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.24573125562E+02  0.24573125562E+02  0.00000000000E+00 0.  1.
       21   -1    0    0  501  503  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00 -0.15553273337E+04  0.15553273337E+04  0.00000000000E+00 0. -1.
        6    1    1    2  501    0  0.98476452980E+01  0.83588711195E+02 -0.62504106700E+03  0.65397965120E+03  0.17300000000E+03 0.  1.
       -6    1    1    2    0  502 -0.98476452980E+01 -0.83588711195E+02 -0.90571314110E+03  0.92592080802E+03  0.17300000000E+03 0. -1.
</event>
<event>
 4   0  0.5048900E-01  0.1782060E+03  0.7546771E-02  0.1169551E+00
       21   -1    0    0  501  502  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.17068413103E+02  0.17068413103E+02  0.00000000000E+00 0.  1.
       21   -1    0    0  502  503  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00 -0.19878188087E+04  0.19878188087E+04  0.00000000000E+00 0.  1.
        6    1    1    2  501    0  0.40928013982E+02 -0.12380831554E+02 -0.73177042255E+03  0.75315691502E+03  0.17300000000E+03 0.  1.
       -6    1    1    2    0  503 -0.40928013982E+02  0.12380831554E+02 -0.12389799731E+04  0.12517303068E+04  0.17300000000E+03 0.  1.
</event>
<event>
 4   0  0.5048900E-01  0.1748201E+03  0.7546771E-02  0.1172912E+00
       21   -1    0    0  501  502  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.50201908406E+02  0.50201908406E+02  0.00000000000E+00 0. -1.
       21   -1    0    0  502  503  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00 -0.81442244278E+03  0.81442244278E+03  0.00000000000E+00 0. -1.
        6    1    1    2  501    0 -0.76531495601E+01 -0.23968586903E+02 -0.16487721432E+03  0.24030513864E+03  0.17300000000E+03 0. -1.
       -6    1    1    2    0  503  0.76531495601E+01  0.23968586903E+02 -0.59934332005E+03  0.62431921254E+03  0.17300000000E+03 0. -1.
</event>
<event>
 4   0  0.5048900E-01  0.2161793E+03  0.7546771E-02  0.1136764E+00
       21   -1    0    0  501  502  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00  0.44614769518E+03  0.44614769518E+03  0.00000000000E+00 0. -1.
       21   -1    0    0  502  503  0.00000000000E+00  0.00000000000E+00 -0.11252245546E+03  0.11252245546E+03  0.00000000000E+00 0.  1.
        6    1    1    2  501    0  0.12142710736E+03 -0.45386865351E+02  0.24023253309E+03  0.32317979501E+03  0.17300000000E+03 0. -1.
       -6    1    1    2    0  503 -0.12142710736E+03  0.45386865351E+02  0.93392706626E+02  0.23549035564E+03  0.17300000000E+03 0.  1.
</event>
```

I am going to generating something like this and the process of generating is not going to be error-free; some of the event entries are going to be malformed and corrupted. How could I detect and remove event entries that are not of the forms shown above using Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I detect and remove event entries that are not of the forms shown above?

What is the specification of your event format?

I've guessed some requirements of your input data and have come up with a not very complicated, but terribly messy regex:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'<event>$'
                r'(?P<body>\s*\d\s+\d'
                r'(\s+(\+|-)?\d+\.\d+(e|E)(\+|-)\d+){4}$'
                r'((\s+[-\d]+){6}(\s+(\+|-)?\d+\.\d+(e|E)(\+|-)\d+){5}'
                r'(\s+[-\d.]+){2}$)+)', re.M)

for match in rx.finditer(your_input_data):
    print(match.group('body'))
```

Take a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/oL6bW8/2) for an interactive explanation of the regular expression. You most likely will have to do plenty of fine-tuning, but it may be a start.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance on using regex in Python. Your solution is very clear the the online regex tester looks very useful (though I think I need to learn about regex a bit more in order to understand it well).